# Android HttpPost not working

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to post data from android to a PHP server.
For some reason, the data is not getting posted.

My data is not getting posted. I have given the code below.
Can any one tell me why this may be happening? The application is not throwing any errors.

```
public void postNow()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient client  = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI uri = new URI(SERVER_URL);
                HttpPost Newpost = new HttpPost(uri);

                List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", value1));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value2", value2));
                Newpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(Newpost);
                Log.v("HTTPResponseOut",response.toString());
            }

            catch(URISyntaxException e ) {

            }

            catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){

            }

            catch(ClientProtocolException e) {

            }

            catch (IOException e) {

            }

        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: How can you tell that it's not throwing any errors when you're catching and ignoring pretty much all of them?

Comment: May I ask if you've tried testing out your REST API with some sort of client like postman for chrome?

Comment: At least, log the exceptions

Comment: Add the following to your catch blocks Log.e("here is an error", "block 1"); block2 for the second 3, 4 and so on, and see the catlog to find out what is happening.

Comment: Try to debug your code and tell what do you get in `HTTPResponse`